# Is .parallelize(...) a lazy operation in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is parallelize (and other load operations) executed only at the time a Spark action is executed or immediately when it is encountered?

See **def parallelize** in [spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fspark%2FSparkContext.scala)

*Note the different consequences for instance for .textFile(...): Lazy evaluation would mean that while possibly saving some memory initially, the text file has to be read every time an action is performed and that a change in the text file would affect all actions after the change.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parallelize` is executed lazily: see L726 of your cited code stating "@note Parallelize acts lazily."

Execution in Spark is only triggered once you call an *action* e.g. `collect` or `count`.

Thus in total with Spark:

1. Chain of transformations is set up by the user API (you) e.g. parallelize, map, reduce, ...
2. Once an *action* is called the chain of transformations is "put" into the Catalyst optimizer, gets optimized and then executed.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it helps to read code comments ;) Strangely, I couldn't find the answer via internet search and my book for learning spark doesn't list parallelize as a transformation. Also, interesting to read about Catalyst.

Comment: I wouldn't categorize `parallelize` as a transformation: it's methods which take RDDs as arguments (and/or receiver) which are split into actions and transformations, and parallelize doesn't.

Comment: parallelize doesn't take RDDs as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

> ...  (and other load operations)

`parallelize` is lazy (as already stated by the [Martin Senne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480892/1560062) and [Chandan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480884/1560062)), same as standard data loading operations defined on `SparkContext` like `textFile`.

`DataFrameReader.load` and related methods are in general only partialy lazy. Depending on a context it may require metadata access (JDBC sources, Cassandra) or even full data scan (CSV with schema inference).

Comment: Interesting that even text files are read lazily. Is the note about .textFile(...) that I wrote in my question correct?

Comment: I assume that the partial laziness in DataFrameReader.load is to give an early warning if things aren't the way they should be?

Comment: There is no reason for `textFile` to be eagerly evaluated. Return type is well defined. DataFrames from the other hand have to determine the structure and depending on a format it requires reading data / reading metadata / analyzing structure.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that here we have just defined RDD, data is not loaded still. This means that if you go to access the data in this RDD it could fail. The computation to create the data in an RDD is only done when the data is referenced; for example, it is created by caching or writing out the RDD.

cited from the [link](http://www.edupristine.com/blog/apache-spark-rdd-transformations-actions)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had trouble finding this answer via search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Not only `parallelize()`, all `transformations` are lazy.

RDDs support two types of operations: `transformations`, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and `actions`, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset.

> All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute their results right away. Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). `The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program`

Have a look at this [article](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) to know all `transformations` in Scala.

Have a look at this [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) for more details.

Comment: I was surprised that despite not being transformations, parallelize and other load operations are lazy. It makes me wonder what else is evaluated lazily in spark.

Comment: I think everything is lazy except actions.